# Can't Run Gremlin Console due to "Exception in thread "main" BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis'... Unsupported class file major version 62"

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin

I'm trying to learn Gremlin, I've installed the console from the website but when I try running the console with "bin/gremlin.sh", I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 62
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:969)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:642)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    ................ (removed for simplicity)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196
    ................ (removed for simplicity)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:965)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: what JDK do you use? You might need to change it, see [this blog](https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/pregel-unsupported-class-file-major-version-62-error-with-jdk-16/m-p/13993)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I had to downgrade my java version to Java 11. I did so using instructions from this website: https://medium.com/@devkosal/switching-java-jdk-versions-on-macos-80bc868e686a

Comment: [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/)* helps with all the JVM/tool handling. (* other tools that do this are available, but I use SDKMan)